# Javascript - Left dropdown menu doesn't disappear when white space is clicked but the right one does despite identical code. Confused

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I click on the choose criteria box, a drop down menu appears. When I click on the white space, or the data table button the drop down menu disappears = good. When I do the same for 'choose data table' the drop down menu doesn't disappear unless I click on the button again, what am I doing wrong? I wonder if it's *because* I have identical code... If I remove the JS for the right side window that allows for the window to disappear upon clicking white space, the opposite happens (the left box's menu disappears but not rifht side).
Full code code below:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDatalist").classList.toggle("show")
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdata')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("datalist-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

function criFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myCriteria").classList.toggle("show")
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropcriteria')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("criterialist-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*START Title*/

h1 { 
color: #46b3d1;
font-family: Gotham;
font-weight: 80;
 }

 /*END title*/

 /*START Database drop down*/
.dropdata {
 font-family: Gotham;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:200px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #46b3d1;
}


.dropdata:hover, .dropdata:focus {
    background-color: #22819b
}



.datalist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: gotham;
}


.datalist-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width:200px;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.datalist-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.datalist a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
 /*END Database drop down*/


/*START Criteria box */

.dropcriteria {
 font-family: Gotham;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:200px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #46b3d1;
}


.dropcriteria:hover, .dropcriteria:focus {
    background-color: #22819b
}


.criterialist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: gotham;
}


.criterialist-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    width:200px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.criterialist-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.criterialist a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}


/*END Criteria box */
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Project Eric</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Project Eric</h1>

<div class="datalist">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropdata">Choose data table</button>
 <div id="myDatalist" class="datalist-content">
  <a href="oxford_ann">Oxford Annual</a>
  <a href="eng_counties">English Counties</a>
  <a href="oxford_qu">Oxford Quarterly</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="criterialist">
 <button onclick="criFunction()" class="dropcriteria">Choose criteria</button>
 <div id="myCriteria" class="criterialist-content">
  <a href="index">Index</a>
  <a href="database">Database</a>
  <a href="filter">Filter</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that only the first window.onclick function was triggered when the click happened.

combine the logic into one method and it'll work as expected.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDatalist").classList.toggle("show")
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropcriteria')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("criterialist-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
  
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdata')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("datalist-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

function criFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myCriteria").classList.toggle("show")
}
```

```css
/*START Title*/

h1 { 
color: #46b3d1;
font-family: Gotham;
font-weight: 80;
 }

 /*END title*/

 /*START Database drop down*/
.dropdata {
 font-family: Gotham;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:200px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #46b3d1;
}


.dropdata:hover, .dropdata:focus {
    background-color: #22819b
}



.datalist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: gotham;
}


.datalist-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width:200px;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.datalist-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.datalist a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
 /*END Database drop down*/


/*START Criteria box */

.dropcriteria {
 font-family: Gotham;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:200px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #46b3d1;
}


.dropcriteria:hover, .dropcriteria:focus {
    background-color: #22819b
}


.criterialist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: gotham;
}


.criterialist-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    width:200px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.criterialist-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.criterialist a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}


/*END Criteria box */
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Project Eric</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Project Eric</h1>

<div class="datalist">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropdata">Choose data table</button>
 <div id="myDatalist" class="datalist-content">
  <a href="oxford_ann">Oxford Annual</a>
  <a href="eng_counties">English Counties</a>
  <a href="oxford_qu">Oxford Quarterly</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="criterialist">
 <button onclick="criFunction()" class="dropcriteria">Choose criteria</button>
 <div id="myCriteria" class="criterialist-content">
  <a href="index">Index</a>
  <a href="database">Database</a>
  <a href="filter">Filter</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved, didn't notice that - I'm very new to Javascript as you can probably tell - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

```js
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDatalist").classList.toggle("show")
}

function criFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myCriteria").classList.toggle("show")
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
 var menus={
  'dropdata':'datalist-content',
  'dropcriteria':'criterialist-content'
 };
 for(var i in menus){
  if(!event.target.classList.contains(i)){
   var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName(menus[i]);
   for(j = 0; j < dropdowns.length; j++){
    if (dropdowns[j].classList.contains('show')) {
     dropdowns[j].classList.remove('show');
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
h1 { 
color: #46b3d1;
font-family: Gotham;
font-weight: 80;
 }

 /*END title*/

 /*START Database drop down*/
.dropdata {
 font-family: Gotham;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:200px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #46b3d1;
}


.dropdata:hover, .dropdata:focus {
    background-color: #22819b
}



.datalist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: gotham;
}


.datalist-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width:200px;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.datalist-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.datalist a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
 /*END Database drop down*/


/*START Criteria box */

.dropcriteria {
 font-family: Gotham;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:200px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #46b3d1;
}


.dropcriteria:hover, .dropcriteria:focus {
    background-color: #22819b
}


.criterialist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: gotham;
}


.criterialist-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    width:200px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.criterialist-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.criterialist a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}


/*END Criteria box */
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Project Eric</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Project Eric</h1>

<div class="datalist">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropdata">Choose data table</button>
 <div id="myDatalist" class="datalist-content">
  <a href="oxford_ann">Oxford Annual</a>
  <a href="eng_counties">English Counties</a>
  <a href="oxford_qu">Oxford Quarterly</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="criterialist">
 <button onclick="criFunction()" class="dropcriteria">Choose criteria</button>
 <div id="myCriteria" class="criterialist-content">
  <a href="index">Index</a>
  <a href="database">Database</a>
  <a href="filter">Filter</a>
 </div>
</div>
```